# pattern matching, static or dynamic binding

Tags: scala, binding, pattern-matching

I wanted to know in a pattern matching, like in the following, do we say that the case classes are bound dynamically or statically?

```
sealed trait Expr
case class Lit(n: Int) extends Expr
case class Add(l: Expr, r: Expr) extends Expr

class Eval {
  def eval(e: Expr): Int = e match {
    case Lit(n) => n
    case Add(l, r) => eval(l) + eval(r)
  }
}
class Printo {
  def printo(e: Expr): Unit = e match {
    case Lit(n) => print(" " + n + " ")
    case Add(l, r) => printo(l); print("+"); printo(r)
  }
}

//Test
object TestExpr { 
  def main(args: Array[String]) {    
    val eval = new Eval    
    val printo = new Printo

    val expr1 =
      Add(Add(Lit(4), Add(Lit(7), Lit(10))),
        Add(Lit(4), Add(Lit(7), Lit(10))))

    val x = eval.eval(expr1)    
    p + "" + println(" = " + x)    
  }
}
```

How I can know if the `Lit(n)` or `Add(l, r)` are called / bound statically or dynamically?

Comment: You can definitely know that all pattern matching is occuring in runtime

Comment: @Odomontois , I couldn't be sure for the pattern matching of `case classes`. Thanks a lot.